# YARD: document custom getter/setter pair like attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I'm using YARD to document my project. YARD document attributes created with

```
attr_accessor :some_attribute
```

in a separate section "Instance Attribute Summary". Now I have another attribute, but with custom setter and getter

```
def some_other_attribute
  # ...
end

def some_other_attribute= value
  # ...
end
```

so basically my question is, how can I get YARD to document this pair of setter/getter just like `attr_accessor` in the previous case, and list `some_other_attribute` within "Instance Attribute Summary"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 0.8 (which is in pre-release right now), the `@!attribute` directive is the recommended way to denote that an object is an attribute. The `@attr_*` tags are deprecated in favour of this directive. You could also do (in 0.8.0+):

```
# @!parse attr_accessor :some_attribute
```

To parse code that isn't necessarily executed by Ruby. Prior to 0.8, you could just add the attr_accessor directly and then redefine the setter/getter as follows:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :foo
  def foo; something_else end
  def foo=(v) something_else(v) end
end
```

Ruby shouldn't mind, except that in `ruby -w` it will warn about method redefinitions. If this bugs you, you can add `undef foo, foo=` in there too. It's a little messy (if you care about -w), which is why we added things like `@!parse` and `@!attribute`.

Comment: Where would you define `@!parse attr_accessor :some_attribute`?

Comment: When mixed attr e.g. `attr_reader :some_attribute` and `def some_attribute=(str)`. I suggest just adding a `# @!attribute [rw] some_attribute` and description for both setter and getter and leave the attr_reader with no comment. Else there is overwritte.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the @attr tag on the class:

```
# @attr [String] name The name of this object. 
class MyClass
  def name
  end
  def name=
  end
end
```

There are other tags (like @attr_reader and @attr_writer) than can also be helpful.